# I need to list all users in Active Directory that do not have any data in the NAME field, using PowerShell

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell

I need to list of all users in AD that do not have any entry in the NAME field (example: smith,jon)

So far I have something like below

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Name -eq " "} | FT SamAccountName
```

I know this fails because of the empty quotations.

Essentially I need a piece of code that "lists all users who have a blank name field"

If there is another way to do this via PowerShell, or if I am just slightly off track with trying the blank quotes, let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to go about this:

`Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!GivenName=*)" | ft samAccountName`

`Get-ADUser -Filter * | Where {$_.GivenName -eq $Null -OR $_.Surname -eq $Null -OR $_.Name -eq $Null} | select samAccountName`

That should work for you.

Added a second command that will check if any of the "name" fields are blank.

Comment: Isn't that the opposite of what he is asking?

Comment: Whoops wrote the wrong condition. Good catch.

Comment: I need a command that outputs users where the NAME field (or any field, such as Surname or GivenName, etc), has no data filled in.

Comment: Is the above command the correct one? Did you edit it from your original post?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I tried this Get-ADUser -Filter { GivenName -eq "$Null" } | ft samAccountName ... it did not work. It listed no users, and I know I have some that do not have a given name

Comment: try the new commands above, I confused my filters.  The $Null works when using the Where statement.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all users where the `Name` attribute is either NULL, empty or consisting only of whitespace you should be able to do so like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | where {[System.string]::IsNullOrEmpty(($_.Name).Trim())} | select sAMAccountName
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this command to work. Once I execute it, it prompts me to "Supply values for the following parameters : Filter". I try and supply a parameter and it fails

Comment: Just updated it, try above

Comment: So I ran what you gave me, and it returned no results (which may mean I have no users with blank NAME fields, good so far). I edited your code to change $_.Name to $_.GivenName and the code blew up. Can I not just do that?